# Change the prompt in spring shell at runtime

Tags: java, spring, shell

is it possible to change the prompt in a spring shell application? For default it seems that the prompt is:

```
shell:>
```

Is is possible to change this text at runtime?

THX

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_promptprovider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `PromptProvider`, see in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_promptprovider

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the answer! I've overlooked this feature. I created this class, put it into my configuration-package and it works good for me:

```
package de.myapp.spring.configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("de.myapp.spring.shell")
public class ShellApplicationConfiguration implements PromptProvider {

    @Override
    public final AttributedString getPrompt() {

        return new AttributedString("myapp:>");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.shell.jline.PromptProvider;
import org.jline.utils.AttributedString;

@Configuration
public class SpringShellConfiguration implements PromptProvider {
    @Override
    public final AttributedString getPrompt() {
        return new AttributedString("myapp:> ");
    }

}
```

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/api/org/springframework/shell/jline/PromptProvider.html